# Display total sum of rows values in arraycollection - Adobe Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I want to display total sum of rows values in an arraycollection. For example:

```
Definition     Value
Product 1      20.00
Product 2      50.00
Product 3      30.00

Total          100.00
```

I have this code:

```
    <mx:DataGrid id="srcgrid">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Definition"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Value"/>
        </mx:columns>    
    </mx:DataGrid>

    <s:Form>
        <s:FormItem label="Total">
            <s:Label text="{total()}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
    </s:Form>
```

And the script:

```
public function total():String {
    var i:Number = 0;
    for each(var obj:Object in ArrayCollection(DataGrid(srcgrid).dataProvider)){
        i = i + obj.Value;
    }

    return i.toString();
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if someone answers correctly the question that you originally posted, we suggest accepting that answer as correct.  If you have further questions, post new questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `total()` function was called before there was anything inside the `dataProvider`.
Also `srcgrid.dataProvider` can be looped as an `Object`

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" applicationComplete="addInitData(event)">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
        <mx:DataGrid id="srcgrid">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Definition"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Value"/>
        </mx:columns>    
    </mx:DataGrid>

    <s:Form x="250">
        <s:FormItem label="Total">
            <s:Label id="total"/>
        </s:FormItem>
    </s:Form>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.events.Event;
            import mx.collections.ArrayList;

            private function addInitData(e:Event = null):void{
                var dataProvider:ArrayList = new ArrayList();
                for (var i:int = 0; i < 12; i++){
                    dataProvider.addItem({Definition : 'item_' + i, Value : i});                    
                }
                srcgrid.dataProvider = dataProvider;
                updTotal();
            }

            private function updTotal():void{
                var sum:Number = 0;
                for (var k:String in srcgrid.dataProvider){
                    sum += srcgrid.dataProvider[k]['Value'];
                }
                total.text = sum.toString();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: @Marcel, you are welcome. Mind accepting the answer?

Comment: yes! That's ok! But I have a question: when I drag and drop a value in datagrid, how do I make to update the total label?

Comment: @Marcel try `<mx:DataGrid id="srcgrid" change="updTotal()">`

Comment: Hi @www0z0k I tried this code but is not work. I create a topic here about this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41704416/update-total-value-datagrid-when-drag-drop-values-adobe-flex